# Query optimization on Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, subquery, case

SQL optimization problem, which of the two solutions below is the most efficient?

I have the table from the image, I need to group the data by `CPF` and `date` and know if the CPFs had at least one `login_ok = true` on a specific date. Both solutions below satisfy my need but the goal is to find the best query.

We can have multiple `login_ok = true` and `login_ok = false` for CPFs on a specific `date`. I just need to know if there was at least one `login_ok = true`

[image]

I already have two solutions, I want to discuss how to make another more efficient

Comment: Please use plain text instead of images, and post the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for your problem:

```
SELECT
    t2.CPF,
    t2.data    
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CPF, 
        date(data) AS data 
    from db_risco.site_rn_login
    WHERE login_ok
    ) t2
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY t2.data
```

DISTINCT would also work, and I doubt it would pose any performance threat in your case. Usually it evals expressions (like date(data)) before checking for uniqueness.

By using a subquery, in this case, you can select upfront which CPFs to include and then extract date. Finally you'd group by on a quite smaller number os lines, since those were previously selected.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has the function `BOOL_OR` to check whether the expression is true for at least one row. It is likely to be optimised for this kind of task.

```
select cpf, date(data) as data, bool_or(login_ok) as status_login
from db_risco.site_rn_login
group by cpf, date(data);
```

An index on `(cpf, date(data))` or even on `(cpf, date(data), login_ok)` could help speed up the query.

On a side note: You may also want to order your results with `ORDER BY`. Don't rely on `GROUP BY` doing this. The order of the rows resulting from a query is arbitrary without a `GROUP BY` clause.